# Unable to update div based on current value inside it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a `php` page that shows the server logs in a web interface. It is pretty simple. Basically there is an `ajax call` inside a `setinterval()` which hits a backend php file, which will read the log and echo it. The relevant code is:

```
setInterval(function()
{
    $.get("log.php",{logId: $('#logId').val()}, function(data)
    {
        $("#logDetails").html(data);

        //scroll to the bottom when updated...
        $("#logDetails").stop().animate({scrollTop: $("#logDetails")[0].scrollHeight}, 800);
    });
}, 2000);
```

As you can see, this just update a div with an id called `logDetails` with content from the log file in the server.

The div has a `style="overflow:scroll"` and the line `$("#logDetails").stop().animate..` is to scroll to the bottom of the div when new content is added. All this works very well.

If a user has scrolled up the div and is examining the logs, and new content comes in then the div scrolls down. That is also fine. The problem is that the server log can have many hours of inactivity. During that time, when the user scrolls up, since setinterval is still working, he gets scrolled down even though new content is not available. This can become a real nuisance.

I wanted to handle this in the minimal way possible and I thought doing this might suffice:

```
$.get("log.php",{logId: $('#logId').val()}, function(data)
{
    //new condition to check id new content has come
    if($('#logDetails').val() != data)
    {
        //update div and scroll to the bottom..
    }
    ...
```

However this is not working. I am aware of other ways like check the log modified time in server side etc, but I cannot modify any of those files due to other reasons.

So my question is - why does this not work? And how can I do this inside the interface file itself instead of resorting to other means?

The PHP code that pushes out the log is:

```
$contents = "";
$handle   = @fopen($logFile, 'r');
if($handle) 
{
    while(($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) 
    {
        //highlight errors
        $txt = "Execution stopped because of error";
        if(strstr($line,$txt))
        {
            $line = "<span style='color:red'>".$line."</span>";
        }

        $contents .= $line;
    }
}
@fclose($handle);
echo nl2br($contents);
```

Comment: Try `$('#logDetails').text()` as `.val()` is for forms fields.

Comment: also, ajax should not be per interval, rather use a callback with a setTimeout

Comment: @Alex - can you explain more? I know the difference between both, but how does setTimeout help better in this use case?

Comment: since ajax is asynchronous you should not run it every n seconds, rather run ajax, wait for it's success function and inside it, run a timeout which in x seconds will run the ajax call again

Comment: @Alex - aah I see what you mean, but in the callback could I not use either of both? setInterval/setTimeout?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j8y9d/

Comment: @UndefinedVariable here is writeup on why to use setTimeout over setInterval:
http://reallifejs.com/brainchunks/repeated-events-timeout-or-interval/

Comment: @UndefinedVariable As an alternative to `setInterval` or `setTimeout`  with AJAX you might consider using [`WebSockets`](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/) as it allows you to open a persistent connection between the client and the server. That way, whenever there is new log information available, the server can automatically push it to the client. This avoids the somewhat inefficient pinging every set interval approach that you're currently using.

Comment: @Alex thanks for the fiddle. But in my case the `clearTimeout` does not really come into play. The web interface is going to keep polling the log for infinity. So I am left with finding a way in the front end to make the decision to update/scroll div.

Comment: you dont have use a cleartimeout, i just wanted to demonstrate it :)

Comment: @JonathanCrowe - there will never be an empty response. This log file will never go beyong 50 lines. In the background other processes keep purging it to have only the latest 50 lines. The web interface merely polls this log and shows it in the UI. I just want it that it should not scroll down the div when the content is stale, but SHOULD scroll down if content has updates. However my if condition never works...

Answer (score 1):

It would be difficult to exactly pinpoint what is wrong since you mentioned the data coming from the log will by dynamic. However you can figure it out by:

- Do a `console.log` of `$('#logDetails').val()` and `data`
- Then use a diff software like `kDiff` to find out what their differences are.

Once you find the differences, then you can think about ways to solve it.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` is unlikely to work, but since you haven't provided the contents of the html you're trying to work with, we can only offer suggestions. try either `$('#logDetails').text()` as mentioned in djidi's comment or `$('#logDetails').html()`.

Comment: I am actually not using any HTML. The log file is a plain text file much like apache's access.log. The only HTML that is added is when I am pushing it to the web  interface as shown in the code above. I tried your methods even before posting, but they did not work. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this to make sure you are only ever getting new data back. Obviously I don't know anything about your system so this would have to be modified to work with the data you have:

```
$contents = "";
$handle   = @fopen($logFile, 'r');
$lastHash = !empty($_GET['last_hash']) ? $_GET['last_hash'] : nulll
if($handle) 
{
    $stale = true;
    while(($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) 
    {
        //highlight errors
        $txt = "Execution stopped because of error";
        if(strstr($line,$txt))
        {
            $line = "<span style='color:red'>".$line."</span>";
        }
        if (empty($lastHash) || md5($line) == $lastHash) {
           // this is the last stale line
          $stale = false;
        }

        if (!$stale) {

            $contents .= $line;
            $lastHash = md5($line);
        }
    }
}
@fclose($handle);
echo json_encode(array('log_data' => nl2br($contents), 'last_hash'=> $lastHash));
```

and in javascript:

```
var lastHash  = null;
setInterval(function()
{
    $.getJSON("log.php",{logId: $('#logId').val(), last_hash : lastHash}, function(data)
    {
        lastHash = data.last_hash
        if (data.log_data && data.log_data.length) {
            $("#logDetails").html(data.log_data);


            //scroll to the bottom when updated...
            $("#logDetails").stop().animate({scrollTop: $("#logDetails")[0].scrollHeight}, 800);});
         }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Sadly, like I mentioned I cannot modify the PHP script due to many reasons - one of them being that what is spits out is consumed by many other apps not under my control. I can only do any changes inside the web interface...